# Unable to authenticate provisioning profile

Tags: ios

Please help me with a recurring problem I am facing while uploading build at device. It asks administrator name and password to proceed, as shown in picture. I input those info and press allow button then same input box appears again. I provide input and it keeps on coming.. I don't have any idea why it is happening.

[image]

Comment: There was an option to enable developer mode on xcode at first run. It configures xcode so it does not require password for every action. You may want to search for this mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this on terminal.

```
DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their reply....but problem is still there...when I run command "DevToolsSecurity -enable " terminal prompts that "Developer mode is already enabled".